# Material UI Transition to SCSS equivalent

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, material-ui, transition

Requesting your kind help me to convert the following Material UI themes to its equivalent SCSS.

I'm considering `up("sm")` as above`600px`. I am creating a @mixin contentShiftContainer so to include it wherever required. However, I am unable to understand the transition portion here in materialUI. I'd appreciate your help. Thanks.

```
 contentShift: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    overflow: "auto",
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(7),
      zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
      transition: theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
      }),
    },
  },
```

What I tried is:

```
@mixin contentShiftContainer{
     display: flex;
     flex-grow: 1;
     overflow: auto;
     flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px){
   .contentShift{
        @include contentShiftContainer;
        margin-left: 7px;
        z-index: 1501;

        //transition for width and margin.
        // -webkit-transition: width 1s ease-in-out;   --> not sure.
    }

}
.contentShift{
     @include contentShiftContainer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theme.transitions.create` is just a convenience function provided by MUI. If you want to know what the output is, you can call the function and look at the output.

Here's some sample code for viewing the output:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material/styles";
const theme = createTheme();
const transition = theme.transitions.create(["width", "margin"], {
  easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
  duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen
});

export default function App() {
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(transition)}</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit theme.transitions.create]

The output in this case is:

```
width 195ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 0ms,margin 195ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 0ms
```

So the CSS would be:

```
transition: width 195ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 0ms, margin 195ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) 0ms;
```